# How to move files from one server to another owned server in PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, apache2

I have two server,

Let's assume first one is content and second is storage.

My viewers see the site from content server and they upload files to that server.

What I want to do is upload them back to storage server and unlink the previous file.

I want to do this in PHP without curl.

Any Idea how to do this ? Remember I have admin access to both servers.

Comment: You can use `ftp` to achieve it easily

Comment: You wrote 'back to storage' . Where does file initially appear? Content or Server?

Comment: Lots of ways: use FTP in PHP if storage server runs FTP server or from content server mount a dir on storage and use rename(), etc. or use exec() and scp.

Comment: @kmsdev It's difficult to be guaranteed about the secure in FTP thefore isn't there any alternatives in PHP ?

Comment: You can use PHP, through **[`ftp_connect()`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.ftp-connect.php)**